# How do you use Windows cmd to run JavaScript on specific page?

Tags: javascript, batch-file, cmd

For example, you could go to the login page of Facebook with Chrome, open the console and type

```
document.getElementById("email").value = "myemailaddress@example.com";
document.getElementById("pass").value = "hunter42";
document.getElementById("login_form").submit();
```

and it would log you in (assuming correct login information).

How would you do this from the Windows cmd or with a batch file?

Automating logging into a website is my main obstacle for creating an automation where a script sends me a text message when I receive a new grade on my school's web portal.

I've experimented with doing a form submission with cURL in PHP, but the login form is very complex with a lot of hidden fields and whatnot.

Personal project aside, I really want to know if you're able to run a JS Script on a specific web page because there are a ton of circumstances where this could be useful.

Thanks!

Comment: use greasemonkey or tampermonkey to easily automate sign-in of any webpage, or do anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do it from the command line (which includes the run dialog). Your best bet is to find a headless browser framework like Selenium or PhantomJS. I've used PhantomJS, CasperJS, and NightmareJS to much success in the past and would recommend them especially if you're familiar with JavaScript already.

Comment: That sounds very useful, thanks! Would there be any issue with the session expiring, though? For example, after having the script log in, would I then be able to navigate to another page on that site and use JavaScript get data from page elements?

Comment: When you use a headless browser, you're afforded the same functionality that you'd have if you opened up the page manually in a Chrome/Firefox session. Session expiration would function the same way.

Comment: I've gotten it working using PhantomJS. Thanks for much for the solution, it was perfect!

Comment: Glad to hear it. I'd suggest playing with Casper and Nightmare as well :) They can be simpler to use if you're going to be doing a lot of that type of work.